# Region Bounds not working on some Pyramid instances

Tags: regions

When I compute the Region Bounds of a simple Pyramid, like:

```
view = Pyramid[{{0., 0., 0.}, {2., 0., 0.}, {2., 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0.5, 0.5, -1.}}];
Graphics3D[view, Axes -> True]
RegionBounds[view]
```

Everything works as expected:

```
Pyramid[{{0., 0., 0.}, {2., 0., 0.}, {2., 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0.5, 0.5, -1.}}]
```

[image]

```
{{0., 2.}, {0., 1.}, {-1., 0.}}
```

But if I come up with the following pyramid, RegionBounds sends an error message despite the pyramid being correctly specified...

```
pyr = Pyramid[{{-2.5, 106., -2.025}, {-2.5, 106., 2.025}, {-1.75, 106., 2.025}, {-1.75, 106., -2.025}, {0., 0., 0.}}]

Graphics3D[pyr, Axes -> True]

RegionBounds[pyr]
```

This produces the return:

```
Pyramid[{{-2.5, 106., -2.025}, {-2.5, 106., 2.025}, {-1.75, 106., 2.025}, {-1.75, 106., -2.025}, {0., 0., 0.}}]
```

[image]

> RegionBounds::reg: Pyramid[{{-2.5,106.,-2.025},{-2.5,106.,2.025},{-1.75,106.,2.025},{-1.75,106.,-2.025},{0.,0.,0.}}] is not a correctly specified region.

But if it's not correctly specified how can I plot it and how does Pyramid[] not show any message?

Add:

I'm running this on version 11.3 student edition on a win10 64bit

Comment: Works on 11.3 Mac OS `{{-2.5, 0.}, {0., 106.}, {-2.025, 2.025}}`

Comment: Works in version 11.3 on Windows 10 both 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the question, the third point of the pyramid should be: {-1.75, 106., 2.025} instead of {-1.75, 106., .025}. The latter also works for me, but not the former.

Comment: @user64494 
 Could you run again the code and see if the bug pops up? Thx

Comment: RegionBounds::reg: Pyramid[{{-2.5,106.,-2.025},{-2.5,106.,2.025},{-1.75,106.,2.025},{-1.75,106.,-2.025},{0.,0.,0.}}] is not a correctly specified region.

Comment: Rationalze helps: pyr = Pyramid[  Rationalize[{{-2.5`, 106.`, -2.025`}, {-2.5`, 106.`, 
     2.025`}, {-1.75`, 106.`, 2.025`}, {-1.75`, 106.`, -2.025`}, {0.`,  0.`, 0.`}}]]

Comment: Thank you @user64494
I've added this workaround in an answer. I tried to credit you but I don't think the @ symbol works on the answer editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve reached out to Wolfram Technical Support and their answer suggests that this is indeed a bug.

> Thank you for taking the time to send this report about RegionBounds. I have been able to reproduce the issue mentioned and, therefore, I have made the proper report to our development team so it can be solved for future versions of Mathematica.

In the meantime, as @user64494 pointed out, using Rationalize seems to solve the issue:

```
Pyramid[ Rationalize[{{-2.5, 106., -2.025}, {-2.5, 106., 2.025}, {-1.75, 106., 2.025}, {-1.75, 106., -2.025}, {0., 0., 0.`}}]]
```